# Why doesn't this C program display a pyramid of asterisks?

Tags: c

I have to make a program that prints a pyramid of asterisk using only while loop

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

I currently have this:

```
/* JJJ */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int k;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter the number of rows of the pyramid: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int i=1;
    while (i<=k)
        {
        int h=1;
        printf("");
        while (k>i)
            {
                printf(" ");
                k--;
            }
        while (h<=2*i-1)
            {
                printf("*");
                h++;
            }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

It only prints an asterisk.

Comment: Your code is not legal C++.  It looks more like `C`.

Comment: And .... what is `printf("");` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Asking for homework help is fine as long as you ask a specific question and show your attempt.

Comment: @ AlbertRenshaw I'm not your mate, bro, and actually this is not a homework problem, this is one of the problems in a quiz I failed to answer. Thanks for the heads up by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly modify the value of `k` in the loop `while (k>i)` that you print the spaces in. The reason why your code displays just one asterisk is that in the iteration of this loop, k's value decreases to 1. So, after the first iteration of the outermost loop, the end is reached. **See this solution:**

♦ No. of asterisks (x) to print on line no. `k` = `2 * k - 1`
♦ No. of spaces to print before x asterisks = `k - (x/2)`

```
int k, i=1, x,y;
printf("Enter no. of lines of the pyramid\n");    
scanf("%d", k);

while(i <= k){
    x = 2*i - 1, y=1;
    while(y <= k - (x/2)){
        printf(" ");
        y++;
    }
    y=1;
    while(y <= x){
        printf("*");
        y++;
    }        
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (k>i)
    {
        printf(" ");
        k--;
    }
```

This loop decreases `k`, which is the only variable you have that tracks how many rows to draw. It causes the outer loop to finish after one iteration.

Don't modify `k`. You could make a copy and modify the copy.

Comment: I didn't down vote but generally answering poor quality questions results in down votes.. even I had few of them :)

Answer (score -1):

The loop is as simple as this, why you make it so hard?

```
int line = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < k-line; ++j)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; ++j)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    line++;
}
```

Comment: I actually need to make this work using only while loop

Comment: well if you really don't know how to convert a for loop to while loop, you need to study the algorithm basics before starting to program.